# If $f$ is linear, then $\sup_{x\in G} f(x) + \sup_{y\in L} f(y) = \sup_{z\in G+L} f(z)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I'm checking if below result is true by giving a proof. Could you verify if my proof is fine?

> Let $G, L$ be subsets of a normed linear space $(E, |\cdot|)$. Let $f:E \to \mathbb R$ be linear and $G+L:=\{x+y\mid x\in G, y\in L\}$. Let $\alpha:=\sup_{x\in G} f(x),  \beta:= \sup_{y\in L} f(y)$, and $\gamma:= \sup_{z\in G+L} f(z)$. Assume that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb R$. Then $\alpha +\beta = \gamma$.

**My attempt:** Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be sequences in $G$ and $L$ respectively such that $f(x_n) \to \alpha$ and $f(y_n) \to \beta$. Such sequences exist by axiom of choice (AC). Then $$\begin{aligned} \gamma &\ge \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n+y_n)\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \big (f(x_n) + f(y_n) \big )\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) + \lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) \\
& = \alpha + \beta.
\end{aligned}$$

By AC, there is a sequence $(z_n)$ in $G+L$ such that $f(z_n) \to \gamma$. By AC again, there exist sequences $(x_n)$ in $G$ and $(y_n)$ in $L$ such that $z_n = x_n + y_n$. Then $$\begin{aligned}
\gamma &= \lim_{n \to \infty} f(z_n) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} f(z_n) \\
&= \limsup_{n \to \infty} \big (f(x_n)+f(y_n)\big) \\
&\le \limsup_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) + \limsup_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) \\
&=\alpha + \beta.
\end{aligned}$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the way you constructed $x_n$ and $y_n$ in the second part, I'm not sure your last equality holds. You just chose $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $x_n+y_n=z_n$, I don't think this guarantees that the limsups are $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
It shouldn't be a problem though, that would just change your last equality to an inequality which still shows what want.

Comment: @Snildt You're right. It's a typo.

Comment: Your proof works. But I suggest trying to prove it without resorting to sequences. Instead choose $a \in G, b \in L, c \in G + L$ with $|f(a) - \alpha| < \epsilon, |f(b) - \beta| < \epsilon, |f(c) - \gamma| < \epsilon$. This is a more broadly applicable proof method. And if done properly, there should be no need for the axiom of choice.